# Does anybody have a GWT 2.1 CompositePlace example?

Tags: gwt, mvp

My app uses Composites and so the current GWT 2.1 MVP example that keeps track of SimplePanels doesn't work for me.

Google [says](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#How_to_navigate) that I can always create my own CompositePlace, CompositeActivity and CompositePlace.Tokenizer, but well.... given my skill level, I am a little reluctant to go that much into uncharted territory.

Does any of the GWT gurus out there have a working example for me?

Thanks

Comment: Their idea for a CompositePlace, etc, is for when you have multiple levels of navigation - NOT for when your places are made out of `Composite`s.  Try their code with the Composites you've built up swapped in for the SimplePanels.

Comment: Yes, but when I do that, example: activityManager.setDisplay(compositeWidget), I get the following error: The method setDisplay(AcceptsOneWidget) in the type ActivityManager is not applicable for the arguments (compositeWidget)

Comment: My theory was that com.google.gwt.activity.shared.ActivityManager.setDisplay(AcceptsOneWidget display) function doesn't accept composites

Answer (score 1):

I found a [blog from "Heros"](http://blog.vivavivu.com/2010/11/think-in-gwt-mvp-framework-activities.html) that had the answer for me.

Turns out the trick is to extend LayoutPanel and implement the AcceptsOneWidget interface.

Then you can pass any LayoutPanel to setWidget function.

Here is the full code:

```
public class OneWidgetLayoutPanel extends LayoutPanel implements AcceptsOneWidget {
    private IsWidget widget = null;

    @Override
    public void setWidget(IsWidget w) {
            if( widget != null) super.remove(widget);
            widget = w;
            if(w != null) super.add(w);
    }
}
```